# Reduce the execution time of queries using tables that holds millions of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, optimization

I'm trying to execute a query that gets the count based on certain parameters. The tables which it operates on is containing 38 million data as of now. The query is taking 6 seconds to execute. I want to bring it down to less than a second as we are using the results to display on a web app.

```
SELECT 
    Policy id,Policy name, COUNT(Policy) COUNT
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         ItemID, OUID, ItemType, ItemGeneratedBy, CreatedDateTime GeneratedDate, 
         Month, OU Agency 
     FROM 
         ItemMaster) IM
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT ItemId, PolicyId 
     FROM ItemPolicy) IP ON IP.ItemId = IM.ItemId
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT PolicyId, PolicyName Policy 
     FROM Policies) P ON P.PolicyId = IP.PolicyID
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT ItemID, ActualActionStr ActionTaken 
     FROM ItemExtension_McAfee) IEM ON IEM.ItemId = IM.ItemId
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT Id, ItemType Channel FROM ItemType) IT ON IT.Id = IM.ItemType
INNER JOIN 
     (SELECT ID, LoginName Violator FROM ItemADUser) IAU ON IAU.ID = IM.ItemGeneratedBy
WHERE 
    IM.OUId IS NOT NULL 
    AND TRIM(Violator) IN ('cusyuk01') 
    AND TRIM(ActionTaken) IN ('affirm')
    AND TRIM(Policy) IN ('G004-Email To External-Affirm')  
    AND GeneratedDate >= '2022-06-11 00:00:00'
GROUP BY 
    Policy, Policy 
ORDER BY 
    COUNT(Policy) DESC
```

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=B1VpV8dKi

The above link is the execution plan for this query.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: Please use Paste The Plan for your execution plan

Comment: Can't access this external link and the query text you have included is rife with errors. Your performance though is going to be poor fore a few reasons, one being you are forcing scans by using non-sargable operators. Consider validating and correcting your data when it's inserted, not queried; also consider pre-aggregating your data so you don't have to repeatedly count unchanging data. If the data changes infrequently perhaps look at a *columnstore* index.

Comment: Um... didn't you post this a few days ago, and I gave an answer? And @Stu above edited my answer (@Stu apparently didn't like me accidentally calling the link 'Paste the plank')

Comment: Anyway, I don't have the previous answer - but to summarise: Your queries are relatively simple/straightforward - there are no big 'group by' or similar - so assuming your query is correct, you're not going to have areas to make to get performance improvements (other than making your WHERE clause sargable). Your two options: buy bigger hardware (more memory, faster disks); or, more realistically, learn about indexing and how to do it. I strongly recommend Brent Ozar's [How to think like the SQL Server Engine](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLDYqU5RH_aX1VSVvjdla9TOKf939UhIDB)

Comment: The [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74887279) was voluntarily removed by the author.

Comment: You've been asked on all 3 of your questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74897477/reduce-the-execution-time-of-queries-using-tables-that-holds-millions-of-rows-wi), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74887279/how-to-reduce-the-execution-time-of-sql-server-database-queries-using-tables-tha), and here) to not use a file sharing site and to use Paste the Plan. Why do you continue to ingore these requests? If you are after free help then you really need to make the effort to help us help you. Deleting your questions and reposting them is *far* from helpful either.

Answer (score 0):

Fix your data so you don't have to perform table scans to apply these predicates

```
AND TRIM(Violator) IN ('cusyuk01') 
AND TRIM(ActionTaken) IN ('affirm')
AND TRIM(Policy) IN ('G004-Email To External-Affirm')
```